# Write test case for android listview click

Tags: robolectric, android-espresso, android-testing, robotium

I have Listview which contain multiples items. I like to click on 1st item of listview by using android test cases.
How can achieve this?

Please help me.

**Listview hierarchy :-**

> MainActivity -> ListFragment -> Listview

Comment: You mentioned two different type of testing and two different libraries. What are you exactly using for test?

Comment: add listview xml and  to know how it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("item_name")))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.view_id)).atPosition(0)
    .perform(click());
```

or

```
onData(hasToString(startsWith("item_name")))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.view_id))
    .perform(click());
```

You can mention the position of the adapter view or no need, default it will take first position